# Iterate though localStorage and sort out corresponding variables

Tags: javascript, local-storage

I have some variables stored in the localStorage, such as

> **Key**: ts_co_1, **Value**: comment 11
>
> **Key**: ts_co_2, **Value**: comment 22
>
> **Key**: ts_ta_1, **Value**: comment 1
>
> **Key**: ts_ta_2, **Value**: comment 2

the length of the localStorage can vary. To every task **ts_ta_i** there is a corresponding comment **ts_co_i**

The code below iterates through the local storage to get all the values. what I want now is the sort these out in tupples or list, so that I can enter these values in a table. i.e. print out the corresponding task and its comment

(ts_ta_1,  ts_co_1)
(ts_ta_2,  ts_co_2)
(ts_ta_3,  ts_co_3)

```
for (var i = 0; i < localStorage.length; i++) {
var key = localStorage.key(i);
var value = localStorage.getItem(key);
console.log('Key: ' + key + ', Value: ' + value);
```

Comment: What is the issue -- what's wrong?

Comment: How/why do you want to sort them? A tuple is an unusual choice of data structure. Why not just send the  localstorage object to your server in it's current form, where you already have it in a clean, payload-friendly dictionary?

Comment: basically the reason behind this is that once the user leave page, the locastorage is set with the input variable then once the user comes back to the page, it will remmember the inputs and present them again in a table. so to auto fill the table i need the sort out the  ts_ta_1 and  ts_co_1, no ned to be in a tupply or list, but an some easy structure that i can use to auto fill the table

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could do something like this:

```
let i = 0, ta, co;
const tuples = [];

while ((ta = localStorage.getItem('ts_ta_' + ++i)) && (co = localStorage.getItem('ts_co_' + i))) {
  tuples.push(`(${ta}, ${co})`);
}

console.log(tuples.join(' '));
```

### Demo

**Ignore the first part** (that's because the actual `localStorage` cannot be used here):

```js
// IGNORE THIS PART (fake localStorage)

class LocalStorageMock {
  constructor() {
    this.store = {};
  }

  getItem(key) {
    return this.store[key] || null;
  }

  setItem(key, value) {
    this.store[key] = value.toString();
  }
};

const _localStorage = new LocalStorageMock;

// Save data to fake local storage for the demo

_localStorage.setItem('ts_co_1', 'comment 11');
_localStorage.setItem('ts_ta_1', 'comment 1');
_localStorage.setItem('ts_co_2', 'comment 22');
_localStorage.setItem('ts_ta_2', 'comment 2');

// Actual code starts here (_localStorage is localStorage in real code)

let i = 0, ta, co;
const tuples = [];

while ((ta = _localStorage.getItem('ts_ta_' + ++i)) && (co = _localStorage.getItem('ts_co_' + i))) {
  tuples.push(`(${ta}, ${co})`);
}

console.log(tuples.join(' '));
```

Comment: excellent, thanks, could you help get each item on the tuples list, i tried for (items in tuples) {
         //console.log(item);
         console.log(tuples[items]); 
        }

Comment: @Ossama Almost: `for (item of tuples) { console.log(item); } `.